# Zendframework - mysql injection how to protect

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, frameworks, code-injection

If I use methods e.g. insert, update in ZF Will I be safe(mysql injection)?

for example a part of code:

```
            $data = array(
                'autor' => $autor,
                'title' => $title,
                'text' => $text,
                'date' => $date,
            );
            $news = new News();
            $news->insert($data); // safe?
```

Comment: May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370163/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-attack-in-applications-programmed-in-zend-framework/7764258#7764258) answer can help.

Answer (score 1):

Similar question here:

[How to prevent SQL Injection attack in applications programmed in Zend Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370163/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-attack-in-applications-programmed-in-zend-framework)

Always make sure you sanitize user input values using [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be fine just the way you have it. I mean one of the advantages of using PDO ext is to prevent SQL injections using PHP instead of MySQL to query the database. 
[Here is more from devzone.zend.com](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1918)

Answer (score 1):

It's fine the way you are doing it. But be careful with mysql-expressions. There you should use a `Zend_Db_Expr`-Object:

```
$data = array(
    'author' => 'John Doe',
    'title' => 'Headline goes here',
    'text' => 'The content...',
    'date' => new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()') //  <--- use this for SQL-Expressions
);
$news = new News();
$news->insert($data);
```

Comment: Actually any expression containing `()` will be converted automaticaly ;)

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html Look at Example #13 and the text above: By default, the values in your data array are inserted as literal values, using parameters. If you need them to be treated as SQL expressions, you must make sure they are distinct from plain strings. Use an object of type Zend_Db_Expr to do this.